# New way of creating (checking for existening) tabs in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I saw many examples with the `find` function but now when I use the newest version (I think 4.1.1a) it says that the find function has been deprecated.

I have this:

```
init: function(){
  this.control({
    'mainMenuTree': {
      itemdblclick: this.itemdblclicked
    }
  });
  this.callParent();
},

itemdblclicked: function itemdblclicked(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
  var itemClicked = record.getData().text;
  var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('centerPanel');
  //var tabBar = tabPanel.getTabBar();
  tabPanel.add({
    xtype: 'tab',
    title: itemClicked,
    id: itemClicked
  });
  //tabPanel.items.find(function(i){console.log(i)});
  //console.log(tabPanel.items);
}
```

So, I need to get an array of tabs to check for the existence of the tab. I don't need the logic, I just need the name of functions or properties to get array of items (id of every tab).

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made it on my own. :) Thanks anyway. :)

```
itemdblclicked: function itemdblclicked(me, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
        var itemClicked = record.getData().text;
        var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('centerPanel');
        //var tabBar = tabPanel.getTabBar();


        var items = tabPanel.items.items;

        var exist = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].id === itemClicked){
                tabPanel.setActiveTab(i);
                exist = true;
            }
        }
        if(!exist){
            tabPanel.add({
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: itemClicked,
                id: itemClicked,
                closable: true
            });
        }
    }
```